# Python moving modules into sub directory (without breaking existing import structure)

Tags: python, import, python-import

Supposing I am writing library code with a directory structure as follows:

```
- mylibrary/
|
|-----foo.py
|-----bar.py
|-----baz.py
|-----__init__.py
```

And to better organise I create a sub directory:

```
- mylibrary/
|
|-----foobar/
|     |-----foo.py
|     |-----bar.py
|-----baz.py
|-----__init__.py
```

I want all client code to keep working without updates so I want to update **init**.py so that imports don't break.

I've tried adding this to **init**.py:

```
from foobar import foo
```

Now if I open a shell I can do:

```
from mylibrary import foo
print(foo.Foo)
```

However if I do this:

```
from mylibrary.foo import Foo
```

I get No module named mylibrary.foo error.
Here is the traceback from my actual example:

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from global_toolkit import section
>>> section.Section
<class 'global_toolkit.serialization.section.Section'>
>>> from global_toolkit.section import Section
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'global_toolkit.section'
>>>
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, but why don't you just create another `__init__.py` inside `foobar/` directory?

Comment: You need to add an `__init__.py` to the `foobar` directory. Then you can do `from mylibrary.foobar.foo import Foo`. There's no need to add anything to any of the `__init__.py` files.

Comment: I was unable to recreate this error, but as the others have pointed out, an `__init__.py` file may solve the problem.

Comment: @ekhumoro I can't do from mylibrary.foobar.foo import Foo because the client code would then break. I'm trying to change the layout of the project without breaking client imports.

Comment: I'm also on Python 3.7 so just adding __init__ somewhere shouldn't make a difference

Comment: @Neil We don't know what are the client imports. Just try to put an empty `__init__.py` inside `foobar/` and check if it works or not.

Comment: @PéterLeéh okay I just tried this. Unfortunately didn't work. Note: I don't know what are the client imports either! I'm just trying to ensure that all imports that worked before the migration still work now, without modification. Perhaps that is not possible though.

Comment: @Neil The problem is that `from foobar import foo` just adds a name to a namespace. You cannot import from a mere name, even if it happens to point to a module object (i.e. it fails for the same reason that `import os as x; from x import path` fails).

Comment: Thank you @ekhumoro that's a good explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this in your `__init__.py` :

```py
from .foobar import foo, bar
import sys
for i in ['foo','bar']:
  sys.modules['mylib.'+i] = sys.modules['mylib.foobar.'+i]
```

Now, `from mylib.foo import Foo` should work.